# sqlalchemy relationship to property of object (rather than object)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to create a relationship which instead of targeting another model class (table), instead targets a property of that model (table)?

Comment: please provide more context

Comment: @van What context would you like?

Answer (score 0):

[`associationproxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) exists to resolve this very problem. It requires an existing relationship - so the result is that there is both the relationship AND the property retrieved across the relationship. Unfortunately, it is not possible to avoid having the relationship, although one could e.g. underscore prefix the relationship.